# How increase the cell height at run time in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

According to the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuOcE.png), the output is a table view. In section 3 the height of each cell is 200. In each cell I have placed one label which has the same height as the cell height i.e. 200. After that I place one more label to display the text from XML which is in gray color. This text is dynamic. I want to resize the cell height according to the this text label because after that I want to place 6 more label to display more data. For your reference you can see in a different color. For that I write following code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all rows:

```
[tableView setRowHeight:44];
```

For each row individually:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //return appropriate value based on IndexPath.row
}
```