# iPhone: How to increase the height of cell dynamically as per the string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using UITableView with header in my app and I want to add string in the cell of tableview. In the cell below the header I want to fill string data and as per the size of the string I want to increase the height of the cell

for better understanding I attach the file.

I have check the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625191/how-to-set-the-cell-height-as-dynamically-in-iphone),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252628/how-to-increase-the-height-of-the-cell-in-a-tableview-in-iphone) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292683/how-increase-the-cell-height-at-run-time-in-iphone-sdk)

but I am not able to get answer which I want.

for better understanding I attach the image too.

[image]

label Instructions indicates my header and in next cell I want to add string.

then How can I increase the height of cell according to string length.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //return appropriate value based on IndexPath.row

  UIFont *font = textLabel.font; // use custom label's font
  NSString *myText = @"your text for row at index path";
  CGSize size = [myText sizeWithFont:font forWidth:textLabel.frame.size.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  return (size.height+20); //10 pixels space above the textlabel and below 10 pixels space
}
```

as mentioned in the link you have referred.

Comment: I am assigning cell value using `cell.textLabel.text`. Do I need anything else ?

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you assign the text thru `cell.textLabel.text` as it is. No need to change. I have edited my answer. Pl. see

Comment: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` I got error msg EXC BAD ACCESS at this line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following delegate method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //return appropriate value based on IndexPath.row
}
```

Within this Method, from the datasource aray, check the length of the string for tht particular row and return the height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this code for cell size.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSString *text =@"your String";

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CellContentWidth - (CellMargin * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FontSize] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);


    return height + (cellMargin* 2);

}
```

## This code use for cell label Height.

```
    NSString *text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(labelwidth , 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    cell.lbl3.frame=CGRectMake(X,Y ,W, height);
```