# Dynamic height for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I am using UIWebView as Content for UITableViewCell. When I add UITableView, I am using some constant height for UITableViewCell. as no content is loaded in UIWebView. when Actual content is added in UIWebView, I am able to get actual height of UIWebView.by using [UIWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

Now problem is UIWebView is with proper height but cell's height in smaller than UIWebView's new height. how I can update height for that cell?

Comment: it may help you or possible duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665812/iphone-how-to-increase-the-height-of-cell-dynamically-as-per-the-string

Comment: I need to implement same way, but in above example its text and in my case I am downloading content from server and then adding in UIWebView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the UIWebView has finished loading you should call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

This will call `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` again will resize your UITableViewCell. In that method you calculate the new height for the cell based on the size of your UIWebView.

Comment: Typo in your "beginUpates". Should be "beginUpdates"

Comment: Where exactly do you put the `*Updates` method calls?

Comment: After updating the objects that are responsible for calculating/returning the height of a cell.

Comment: how do you do that given the objects are in the uitableviewcell? it just ends up in an infinite recursive call...

Answer (score 2):

put this Method in your code it will work

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [[arrLocation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize.height + 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside this method you can change the row height dynamically

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: In - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView 
{                                                      [iListTableView beginUpdates];
[iListTableView endUpdates];                                                         } calling this but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this sample for help:

http://github.com/penso/webview-in-tableview

Try this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.title = @"Webview in UITableView";
        webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)]; // Don't use CGRectZero here, won't work
        webview.delegate = self;
        webview.hidden = YES;

        [webview loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] 
                              initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];

        [self.tableView setTableFooterView:webview]; // Leave this, else you'll have rows to fill the rest of the screen

    }

    - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        float newSize = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] floatValue];
        NSLog(@"Resizing webview from %.2f to %.2f", webView.frame.size.height, newSize);
        webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, newSize);
        webView.hidden = NO;

        // We need to reset this, else the new frame is not used.
        [self.tableView setTableFooterView:webview];
    }
```