# UIWebView not correct height on webview finish loading

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview, uicollectionview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have collection view where in cell I put UITableView.
Two of cells in that table view contains UIWebView.
I need to calculate height dynamically of UIWebViews. So I do next in

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

.....
     CGFloat webViewHeight = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]floatValue];

But problem is that height on result calculates using content that was upload previously when this cell was used for another object from array.  I have try to fix that problem using next thing
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body = \"\";"];
But it doesn't help me. It works fine at simulator but buggy at device. + If I put delay before upload new html

```
[webView loadHTMLString:sourceHTML baseURL:nil];
```

I could see previous content that leads to calculating to wrong height.

**Update 1**
Here is solution that works perfect for me

```
CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    webView.frame = frame;
```

And from frame I can get correct height.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by calling these two functions in your `webViewDidFinishLoad` function to reload the height for the cells without reloading the data:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

If you need to know the height before the initial data load then your only option is to load the `UIWebView` prior to initializing the table. Then you would assign the preloaded `UIWebView` to the cell's `webView` property in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742151/dynamic-height-for-uitableviewcell)